# plotly - interactive outlier filter for scatter plots

Tags: python, d3.js, plotly

I'm plotting a [scatter plot](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/) with plotly, and it has outliers that make the graph unfriendly. Is there a simple way to add a widget/lever/combobox that allows the user to input a number `freq` - which interactively filters out points with less than `freq` in their `y` coordinate and then does autoscale to fit the new graph? Or will this require some complex coding?

NOTE: I can't do this filtering up-front as the graph data isn't static and its hard to know up-ahead what would `freq` be to be considered as an outlier...

Comment: wouldn't setting the upper limit of the y-axis to `freq` achieve the same result?